# Bias while converting CMU Sphinx's confidence score to probability

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, probability, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to convert output of CMU Sphinx's recognizer
(i.e. list < hypothesis (i.e. phrase), score (in log) > obtained by tweaking test_ps_nbest.c)
to following form:
list < hypothesis (i.e. phrase), "probability" (between 0 and 1) >

A trivial method which I am using now is as follows:

1. Divide each confidence score by language weight (eg: 11)
2. Normalize the list of confidence score in log domain
3. Output probability = exp(normalized confidence score)

The problem is that the output probability from above method is biased. Do you have any suggestions that I can use to get the bias in the probability ?

Example method that I have to implement to correct the bias:

vector < double > getBias(vector < string > phrases, vector < double > logConfidenceScores)

Example input for above discussion:

< "HE GOT IN OUR HEAD HEART LUNG AND HE MARKED IT", -43278 >

< "HE GOT IN OUR AT OUR CLASSES MONEY AND HE MARKED IT", -43449 >

< HE GOT IN POWER AT HEART LUNG AND HE MARKED IT",  -43368 >

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> A trivial method which I am using now is as follows:
> Divide each confidence score by language weight (eg: 11)
> ```

First of all it's not a confidence score but a score. Why do you divide? The score in the list is acoustic score too, language weight doesn't have any sense here

> ```
> Normalize the list of confidence score in log domain
> ```

This is also a senseless thing because of huge probability mass you do not account for.

> ```
> Output probability = exp(normalized confidence score)
> ```

The sequence of actions does not have any mathematical sense, not strange you didn't get a good result.

If you want a per-utterance confidence score you might want to review a theory first:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.6890&rep=rep1&type=pdf